# I don't want Windows SYSTEM to be able to delete folder

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, files-folders, sdelete

Here is my problem:
I've got a folder with a "dekstop.ini" file inside and some files and folders inside too.
I've tried to make this folder undeletable by the security tab in property:
So, I've remove the inheritance and deny "delete, change permissions, Take ownership" for this folder only.
For ME (administator) and SYSTEM in the Permission entries in the Advanced Security settings for THIS FOLDER.

But It does nt work.
Ican still delete this folder, or the system can.

Could it be possible?
could it be possible with Powershell instead?

For Powershell:
the folder is there: "D:\folder\folder\THESPECIFICFOLDER"
the icon is there: "E:\folder\folder\folder\ICONFORTHESPECIFICFOLDER.ico"

If, It will be possible to not delete as well as THESPECIFICFOLDER the "desktop.ini" file inside THESPECIFICFOLDER.
All the others files and folders could be deleted of course.

thank you very much for your help.

regards.

Comment: It is well known that the Windows 'LocalSystem, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' is the highest privilege in the Windows OS. You cannot restrict what it does, that is why it exists. PowerShell cannot control this. You have to go through special hoops to even use itr

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your answer. in this case could I make my desktop.ini file uneletable? But of course as I always do it must stay read only (Idid it for myself and the system. thank you for your answer